# Incheon Airport Transit Questions

Tags: transit, airports, south-korea, seoul

I’m going to Seattle from Cebu via Incheon.
I wanted to know, if I land in Incheon, go through security for my connecting flight and go up to the passenger terminal (where the boarding gates are), is it possible to exit said passenger terminal?

Because I want access to some transit facilities (i.e free showers) in the passenger terminal before heading out to the city to kill time during a long layover. As I searched, there are no such facilities in the arrivals area.

I know Incheon offers free tours but I wanna go out on my own and I won’t need a visa as I’m a US citizen.

Answer (score 2):

Nope, not possible. Once you're in the departure area, you can only go out one way (under normal circumstances): on a plane. If you want to visit Seoul, you have to go through Immigration like regular passengers.

Note that it might prove impractical if you have a shortish layover (anything under 12 hours), because the round trip gate to Seoul and back to your next gate will be 4 hours+, depending on the time of day. Passport control when arriving takes forever unless you're really lucky, and going downtown takes at least an hour, depending where you're going. On the way out, security checks and Immigration also take a long time (few X Ray machines opened, even during rush hours). And depending on the airline, you might have a way to go to reach your gate. Incheon is huge.

Comment: Yeah.. Well, I know I’ll have to go through Immigration if I wanna go out. But bummer. So there’s no way to exit the passenger terminal once you’re in it, eh?